# Ruby object.attributes.each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, hash

Currently I am working on simple Ruby on Rails web application, were I need to output some data to user.
Data to output is all attributes of selected object. Currently I am achieving it by using 
a simple loop shown below

```
<%= @event.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
   <%= attr_name.humanize.titleize %>
   <%= attr_value %>
<% end %>
```

Everything works like a charm, except I get data (I believe hashes), which I do not want to see in curly brackets like:

> {"id"=>30, "title"=>"Kim and Jim Wedding", "created_at"=>Sun, 27 Apr 2014 16:41:34 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sun, 27 Apr 2014 16:41:34 UTC +00:00, "venue"=>"Skinners hall", "post_code"=>"n78db", "description"=>"Wedding reception for 160", "staff_need"=>12, "price"=>5600.0, "profit"=>700.0}

Is there any chance I can hide this block? Or I should just loop every attribute in object manually like @event.id, @event.title, etc. instead of using attributes.each? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<%= @event.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
```

To

```
<% @event.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>  ## Removed =
```

You are seeing a hash displayed in the view because you are rendering `@event.attributes` which I suppose you don't need to.

`<% %>` is for evaluation of Ruby expression and `<%= %>` for evaluation plus rendering the result of Ruby expression. In your case, you simply need `<% %>`